# Jsoup - how to scrape radio website for currently playing song?

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm making a program using jsoup to scrape a certain radio website for the currently playing song and artist. I've followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C1b74N1rgQQ but could not get the correct data from the website.

I want to access this radio website: https://indie88.com/ and display the song (and artist) which is currently playing.

Here's my code so far:

```
package jsoupTest;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;

public class indie88 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Document document = (Document) Jsoup.connect("https://indie88.com/").get();
    Element e = document.getElementById("page");
    String text = e.getElementsByTag("span").get(2).text(); 
    System.out.println(text);

}
```

By running this code I get "search". I think it has something to do with the .get(2) or the "span" tag in the html but I'm not sure. This is my first time working with jsoup and any advice would be helpful on how I can get it to display the song currently playing (which is at the top of the page).

Also - how do I know when to use getElementsByTag and getElementsByClass, etc? Is there a way to specify which "span" tag to use? It seems to not be getting information from the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go to https://indie88.com/ with the browser, the site loads few more files. The info that you are looking for is present at https://indie88.com/wp-content/themes/indie88/inc/streamon.php, so in order to get it, try the following:

```
final String url = "https://indie88.com/wp-content/themes/indie88/inc/streamon.php"; 
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
System.out.println(doc.body().text());
```

And a sample output is -

> {"artist":"Fountains of Wayne","title":"Stacey's Mom","end":"1522993371.161780"}

Now you can use some JSON library or regex to extract the artist and title.

Comment: How did you know to go to that url to get the information? Would I be able to do this for other radio websites?

Comment: Well, each site is differnt from other. In this case I've opened my browser's dev tools and checked which files it downloads from the site. Then I've checked these files to see if any of them contains the information. Some sites use JS to display information, so in these cases jsoup is not useful. This time it was simple, but as I said - each site may require different technique.